# SD card won't mount to Moto G

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, external-sd, sd-card, motorola-moto-g, mount

I've had a 64g card in my phone for months now, then all of a sudden (I believe after I updated to Lollipop) I began to receive errors saying the card was unexpectedly removed even though it was still in my phone. So I've tried to remove it and put it back in while the phone was both turned off and on with no success. My external storage settings don't even show the card is in my phone. I'm not super tech savvy so I don't know how to reformat and all that. Any simple fix?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, reformatting the card seems to be the best option but may not help anyway. There probably isn't a simple fix. There's lots of guides on how to format an SD Card in FAT32 but I'll give a quick overview for a Windows PC. Please be aware that this will wipe all data from the SD Card:

1. Backup data from the card using Windows Explorer.
2. In `Computer` or `This PC`, right-click your SD card and click 'Format'. Make sure FAT32 is selected and then confirm the operation.
3. Power off your device and insert the SD Card.
4. When the device boots, it should (hopefully) recognise the SD Card.

Comment: OK, awesome. Post back here if you need further help!